# How can I use a user's own SMS service to send OTP and make mobile number verification in my Android app?

Tags: java, android, security, android-security

I have created a small way to do this.

It is as follows first i generated a small random 6 digit code (OTP)

```
int otp = new Random().nextInt(900000) + 100000;
```

then,
I send this OTP to user entered mobile number that i have to verify,
i am using user's own sms service to do this

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(user_mobile.getText().toString(),null,"Otp for verification is: "+otp,null,null);
```

then,
I create Intent, start new activity and pass OTP to new activity

```
Intent itn = new Intent(MainActivity.this,OtpPage.class);

itn.putExtra("Otp",s_otp); 

startActivity(itn);
```

and then,
I just let user enter the OTP he received from SMS and verify it with OTP i received from previous activity using Intent if both are same i verify the mobile number,

Now my question is, **Is this valid way to do this or it contains some security flaws,
if yes what security problems may arise here?**

Comment: should you not be asking this [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/) perhaps

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in it. It is secure. This is because android only with think that you are sending an sms and nothing else. Also other app use it. Because Firebase Auth show a reCaptcha on a web page, many apps have done it.

##### But you are doing a wrong method for creating an OTP.

You can use this instead

```
private int createOtp(){
    int otp = new Random().nextInt(9) + new Random().nextInt(9) + 
              new Random().nextInt(9) + new Random().nextInt(9) + 
              new Random().nextInt(9) + new Random().nextInt(9);

    return otp;
}
```

Now you can assign it in this way -> `int otp = createOtp();`